# Awk - average from intervals given in separate file

Tags: awk

I have two files.

```
$cat file1.txt
1   5
2   5
3   6
4   7
5   5
8   2
```

I would like to report the average of column $2 for intervals of column $1 specifed in files2.txt.

```
$cat file2.txt
range1  1   3
range2  5   7
range3  2   5
range4  6   8
range5  6   7
```

Desired output:

```
range1  1       3       5.333
range2  5       7       1.667
range3  2       5       5.75
range4  6       8       0.667
range5  6       7       0
```

Note that values in $1 are consecutive integers but some numbers (eg. 6 and 7) maybe missing. In this case values in column $2 are assumed to be 0.

Ideally I would like an awk solution. Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk array assistance needed - averaging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515666/awk-array-assistance-needed-averaging)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - but I can't see how to extrapolate the suggestions from your link to my problem which gives the range and column to average in two separate files. I don't know where to start with this one. As soon as I think of anything I will post. Ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '
NR==FNR { 
    a[$1] = $2; 
    next 
}
{ 
    sum = count = 0; 
    for(x=$2; x<=$3; x++) { 
        sum+=a[x] 
    }
    printf "%s\t%.3f\n", $0, sum/(($3-$2)+1)
}' file1 file2
range1  1   3   5.333
range2  5   7   1.667
range3  2   5   5.750
range4  6   8   0.667
range5  6   7   0.000
```

Comment: Brilliant! This has taught me a lot. Can I ask whats the purpose of "sum = count = 0" I see it a lot and I know that the code works without it.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. We are just initializing our variables back to 0 after the lines are printed. Actually we don't need count variable. That must be from my older code I had posted. You just need the sum variable. But we do need to set it to 0.